# Websocket(ws) nodejs handle error "ENOTFOUND "

Tags: node.js, websocket

How to handle the error: `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND unexistantwebsite.com` with the node package [Websocket(Ws)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) without making the app crashing ?

I just tryed to create a websocket connect on an non-existant website and that make all the app crashing :

```js
 var ws = new WebSocket('wss://unexistantwebsite.com/', {
        binaryType: "arraybuffer"
    });
```

[image: error]

I tried many way to handle the error but nothing works.

- Surround with try catch: **KO**
- Add `.catch` on the constructor end: **KO** (even invalid that's normal I suppose)

I just want to handle the error avoiding the app to crash.

Comment: `ws.on('error', someFunction)`

Comment: Doesn't work, the first stuff I tried @jfriend00